# using geany with python virtual environment

Tags: python, geany

I am just starting to set up virtual environments for my Python projects.
Up to now I have used and like Geany for development and testing.
When I set up my new virtual environment, what will I need to set in Geany to make sure it runs my Python code in the appropriate venv?

Thanks!

Comment: read more here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105941/how-do-i-make-python3-the-default-python-in-geany

Answer (score 4):

Start by creating a project file that resides in your `venv` folder. Then, point to the Python interpreter that resides in the `venv` folder using the build configuration feature.  These actions will allow you to run the correct Python interpreter for each virtual environment you create and not affect the configuration of other virtual environments, other project configurations, or your base configuration.

To set Geany up so that it runs Python code in the appropriate `venv`, follow these steps:

1) Verify Geany is set up for Project Sessions. To do this, go to the main menu, select 'Edit', then 'Preferences'. The Preferences window will appear. Select the General Tab, then select 'Miscellaneous' tab. Now look at 'Projects' section on the tab. Verify both 'Use project-based session files' and 'Store project file inside the project-based directory' are selected.

2) Create a Geany project file in your `venv` folder. To do this, go to the main menu, select 'Project', then select 'New'.  Give the project a name and save it in your virtual environment folder.

3) Configure the build commands for the above project. To do this, go to the main menu, select 'Build', then select 'Set Build Commands'. A window will appear. Look for the 'Execute' button on the bottom left of the window. In the command box next to the 'Execute' button type in the complete path to the bin folder in your `venv` folder that contains the Python interpreter you wish to run, then add "%f" to the end of the command.  For example, my virtual folder is in `home/my_virtual_env_folder` and I want to run the Python3.4 intrepreter in that folder, so I would type in:
`/home/virtual_env_folder/bin/python3.4 "%f"`

Click 'OK' and the changes you made will be saved. Now when you open the project you just created, the project file will automatically point to the correct Python interpreter for the `venv` you are working in.

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and format the text.

Comment: This means, the same process must be gone through for EACH single venv project?!! Sounds ridiculous!

Answer (score 2):

I am using Windows 10 and conda virtual environments, which I first have to activate before use. I was able to use these conda environments in Geany 1.36 by doing the following:

1. Go to menu: Edit - Preferences, in there go to Tools tab and in Terminal, type the following:

   **cmd.exe /Q/C conda activate envname && %c**

   - Replace "envname" with the name of your conda virtual environment.
   - && will also pass the argument %c to the execution line.
   - %c will pass the command in execute command from Geany (step 2).
2. Go to menu: Build - Set Build Commands, in there go to "Execute commands" section, and in Execute Command, type the following:

   **python "%f"**

   - %f will pass the name of the file that you are executing from.

In the end it's like you are executing the following (assuming your python file is "script.py"):

cmd.exe /Q/C conda activate envname && python script.py

This worked for me. Just a note, when I installed miniconda, I added it to the PATH variables in Windows 10. That is why I don't have to add the path where the activate.bat or python.exe are located, they are already declared in the PATH variable from Windows.

Comment: This works perfectly in my Windows 10 and Geany 1.38

Answer (score 0):

This works for win10/11 python venv, in a cmd window, enter:

```
cmd /k path\to\venv\activate\activate.bat
```

in a .bat file to get a cmd widow then type geany.

Or a .bat file with:

```
path\to\activate.bat && Z: && cd Z:\path\to\project && python project.py
```

double click will launch your python file and destroy the cmd window on exit.