# RaspberryPi: ImportError: No module named cv2 in Geany

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, geany

I installed opencv in RaspberryPi (using [this](https://pysource.com/2018/10/31/raspberry-pi-3-and-opencv-3-installation-tutorial/) link)and import in termial and python3 (idle). It shows no error in these two as shown in below images.

[image]
[image]

But, when I tried to run import cv2 in Geany, it shows error given below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Does geany point to your python3 installation or to python 2? If no, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105941/how-do-i-make-python3-the-default-python-in-geany

Comment: Thanks @Dschoni. I solved by the link which you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by changing python to python3 in Geany. 
For this, Go to `Build->Set Build Commands` in Geany menu. In `Set Build Commands`window, under `Python commands` label in compile line `python m py_compile` will be there. Similarly, under `Executive commands` label in executive line `python "%f"` will be there. I changed `python m py_compile` into `python3 m py_compile` and `python "%f"` into `python3 "%f"` (*as shown in images 1 and 2*) and above-mentioned problem get solved.

**Image 1.**

[image]

**Image2.**

[image: **enter image description here**]

Thanks.